# Where to put "defer req.Body.Close()"?

Tags: go

I have `net/http` handlers that have `defer req.Body.Close()` in each on web server side.

What is the correct place to put this in? Should I put it in the end of the function or does it matter at all, and I can put it in the beginning?

Comment: If you place  `defer req.Body.Close()` at the end, you wouldn't need the `defer` keyword, but you risk that you or any future programmer touching the code accidentally add code that returns from your function early , and then `req.Body.Close()` wouldn't run.

Comment: It's not stressed / clear, but are you asking about `http.Handler`, being at server side, serving incoming requests? Or being the client, making outgoing HTTP requests to other servers?

Comment: @JimB That's actually the answer, post it.

Comment: @icza: I figured I'd find a dup, but no luck ;)

Answer (score 89):

A request body does not need to be closed in the handler. From the [`http.Request` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request)

```
// The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP
// Handler does not need to.
```

Answer (score 11):

### `net/http`

#### Server requests

Clarified at [2ede818](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/2ede818ae0761fc57dc1b52b4c8673933a3ff3fa), `net/http` states that:

> For server requests, the Request Body is always non-nil but will return EOF immediately when no body is present.
>
> **The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP Handler does not need to.**

Comment: That is to say, you should NOT close the request body in the call stack for ServeHTTP Handler.

Answer (score 9):

> What is the correct place to put this in? Should I put it in the end of the function or does it matter at all, and I can put it in the beginning?

Neither nor. Both are terribly wrong.

The `defer req.Body.Close()` has become cult.

Hard facts first:

1. If the request failed (non nil error returned) there *is* no Body to close, neither in a defered way nor a direct way.
2. You must close the Body (if present) on all code paths you might take.
3. You probably do not want to close the Body before having processed it (or at least parts of it).

Back to the options in your question:

- "at the beginning [of the function]": Totally wrong as Body might be nil (fact 1).
- "at the end [of the function]": Totally wrong because of A) it is dangerous as you might miss a code path leaving your function (fact 2) and B) even if you equip all your function ends (i.e. returns) with `defer Bod.Close()` it is totally *useless* to defer it instead of simply closing it via `Body.Close()`.

The *only* sensible way of defered closing the request body is once, right after having established that Body is non-nil what means the request did not return an error.

Comment: I will just leave it here: `For server requests the Request Body is always non-nil`...

Comment: This answer only applies to "CLIENT" side http request. Server side (as asked in question) does not need to close.

(but your answer *is* useful when applied to Client side)

Comment: @DenisV unless you're testing your controllers and you create your own request, but neglect to add a body to your request (i.e. by using `http.NewRequest("some method", "some path", nil)`)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the documentation, no need to explicit close it both in client and server side.

```
// Body is the request's body. 
// 
// For client requests, a nil body means the request has no 
// body, such as a GET request. The HTTP Client's Transport 
// is responsible for calling the Close method. 
// 
// For server requests, the Request Body is always non-nil 
// but will return EOF immediately when no body is present. 
// The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP 
// Handler does not need to.
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Go [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) it is up to you to close the body once you are done with it.

I usually put the defer line right after the line where I check the request for errors.

Comment: This answer only applies to "CLIENT" side http request.

Server side (as asked in question) does not need to close.