# Should I close request body if I use io.TeeReader() or io.ReadAll()?

Tags: http, go, request, handler, middleware

I have a handler which I call from my `main()` function:

```golang
type requestBody struct {
    Query string `json:"query"`
}

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

  r.Post("/api", MyHandler(superGraph, gqlGen))
}

func MyHandler(library *MyLibrary, next http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0))

        reader := io.TeeReader(r.Body, buf)

        var reqBody requestBody

        err := json.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&reqBody)

        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "cannot read body", http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        res, err := library.DoSomething(...)

        if err != nil {
            log.Error(err)

            err := r.Body.Close()
            log.ErrorIf(err)

            r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(buf)

            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }

        render.JSON(w, r, res) // go-chi "render" pkg
  }

}
```

#### QUESTION

Do I need the below line?

```golang
err := r.Body.Close()
```

I know https://stackoverflow.com/a/42533540/10088259:

> A request body does not need to be closed in the handler. From the http.Request documentation:

> The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP
> Handler does not need to.

but here I'm using:

```golang
reader := io.TeeReader(r.Body, buf)
```

and `if err != nil {`

```golang
r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(buf)
```

So, should I `r.Body.Close()` it in the `if` path of my code considering that `ioutil.NopCloser()` has a "fake" `Close()` method?

Comment: You shouldn't be overwriting `r.Body` in the first place - what are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: @Adrian, thanks for your answer. I wanna do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695231/using-two-handlers-for-a-graphql-project-handle-query-with-the-second-one-if-th

Comment: The net/http server ignores Request.Body after the handler is called.  An application can modify Request.Body as shown in the question.  There's no need to close Request.Body or create a fake Cloise() method.

Comment: @MuffinTop I'm afraid about memory leaks...

Comment: Go has a GC.  Memory leaks are not a concern.

Comment: It certainly doesn't hurt to close the body. httputil.DumpRequest does it too.

Comment: @Peter what does it mean `doesn't hurt`?

Comment: That it will not cause a problem.

Comment: @Peter but it's useful or not? I have had a great many different answers.

Comment: Yes, people seem to disagree on this and I'm not sure myself, to be honest. Hence my advice to just leave the Close call in, because it doesn't hurt and the standard library does it too in a very similar situation.

Comment: [This CL](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/b1050542c1dcff9f5902ab2745aae3ccc8340c11) makes it safe to set Request.Body without the application closing the original value of Request.Body.  If you are concerned, then go ahead and close the original body.

Comment: @MuffinTop thanks for your answer. My doubt is because I'm using `r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(buf)` to write again in `r.Body`...